# Assembly Console Pause

Tags: assembly, console

Like C & C++ we use "system("pause");" how to pause console in MS Visual Studio 2010 assembly language

```
.586
.model flat   ;,stdcall

.stack 4096

.data
    number DWORD -105
    sum    DWORD ?

.code
   main:nop
     mov eax,number
    add eax,158
    mov sum,eax

    mov eax,0
    ret



   end main
```

where i have to change this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a small C program that uses system("pause"), and change the project setting to output assembly code. Use the generated assembly code to determine the naming and calling convention for system().

Comment: Create a new windows console program (empty project) with Visual Studio. Write a program that does a call to system("pause"). Right click on the project name, then properties, then C / C++, then output files, and then change assembly output on the menu box from "no listing" to "assembly with source code". Do this for both debug and release. Then build a debug and a release version The assembly files will end up in the debug and release folders. The release version should be good enough, but you may want to look at the debug version which will have extra code in it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this statement in .code section after display what you want

```
.code
;write your code
call Waitmsg
```